# "Multi-Step" commands while using CMD.exe in C#

Tags: c#, windows, cmd

I'm trying to use "multi-step" command in a c# script, for example the command "net user usrname *" contains 3 steps to enter a password and then validate, i don't know if it is possible to send extra arguments while the Process is running

My code:

```
Process p = new Process();
p.StartInfo.WindowStyle = System.Diagnostics.ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
p.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
p.StartInfo.FileName = "cmd.exe";
p.StartInfo.Arguments = "/C " + command;
p.StartInfo.WorkingDirectory = startupFolder;
p.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
p.StartInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
p.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
p.Start();
string output = p.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
string error = p.StandardError.ReadToEnd();
```

Comment: Redirect standard input and feed it strings.

Comment: RedirectStandardInput=true and writes string to p.StandardInput stream

Comment: i'll try this technique thx

Comment: Basic ways are creating a .bat file or using the && or || operator to tell Cmd.exe you specified more than one command.  Do pay attention to error handling, the odds that this implodes in an undiagnosable mess when one of the commands fail are high.

Comment: The thing is i don't want to execute multiple commands at once, i just want to enter arguments in the command after executing, for example when you type date in the cmd the console asks you a value.

Comment: `net user usrname *` isn't a practical example. Many console applications that read a password do so via `ReadConsole`, which will fail if `StandardInput` is redirected to a pipe. It's also a bad example of a single command to run via the shell because there's no point in running net.exe via cmd.exe; just run it directly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would concatenate each command with "&".  For example, "cmd /k echo Test 1 & echo test 2".

Edit:

I created a remote control/remote admin solution a while back that uses this same technique to allow you to run batch and PowerShell scripts against remote computers via the web portal.  As shown in the below screenshot, it works.

[image]

The C# that executes the command can be found here:  https://github.com/Jay-Rad/InstaTech_Client/blob/master/InstaTech_Service/Socket.cs#L614

```
if (cmdProcess == null || cmdProcess.HasExited)
{
    var psi2 = new ProcessStartInfo("cmd.exe", "/k " + command);
    psi2.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
    psi2.RedirectStandardInput = true;
    psi2.RedirectStandardError = true;
    psi2.UseShellExecute = false;
    psi2.WorkingDirectory = Path.GetPathRoot(Environment.SystemDirectory);

    cmdProcess = new Process();
    cmdProcess.StartInfo = psi2;
    cmdProcess.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
    cmdProcess.OutputDataReceived += async (object sender, DataReceivedEventArgs args) =>
    {
        jsonMessage.Status = "ok";
        jsonMessage.Output = args.Data;
        await SocketSend(jsonMessage);

    };
    cmdProcess.ErrorDataReceived += async (object sender, DataReceivedEventArgs args) =>
    {
        jsonMessage.Status = "ok";
        jsonMessage.Output = args.Data;
        await SocketSend(jsonMessage);
    };
    cmdProcess.Start();
    cmdProcess.BeginOutputReadLine();
    cmdProcess.BeginErrorReadLine();
}
else
{
    cmdProcess.StandardInput.WriteLine(command);
}
```

Comment: thanks for your answer, I tried but it don't work so i don't know what to do

Comment: Can you elaborate on "doesn't work"?  Specificity is important.  :)